# Passports with different names, check-in, ticket name, and immigration problem!

Tags: visas, passports, italy, dual-nationality, ethiopia

Just the account to find out answers to this problem, hopefully it can be solved :)

So I will be travelling from Ethiopia to Amsterdam. I have an Italian and Venezuelan passports. Here is the case:

My flight has my venezuelan name, which is the same as the one in my Italian passport but with the second last name used in spanish naming customs. This was a mistake since I plan on travelling with my Italian passport, but I forgot that my Italian passport doesn't have my second last name.

When I am in the gate in Ethiopia, the airline will check if I can legally enter with my venezuelan passport to the Netherlands (its the one I have to travel with because of the name in the ticket), and my Venezuelan passport expires before the 3 months of arriving, therefore I cannot use it to enter europe. I could enter perfectly with my Italian passport, but when doing the check-in they would check my venezuelan passport since it is my ticket.

Is it ok to check-in with my venezuelan passport because of the name, and show them that I can legally enter europe because of my Italian passport?

I cannot change the name because this is only the return ticket, but during my way there my Venezuelan passport did have the 3 months before expiring so maybe that's why it worked. I remember was checking in with my Italian and they said "Name does not match, do you have another passport?" and then it was fine.

Thank you all!

Comment: That’s the best you can do under the circumstances and hope.

Comment: I also have dual citizenship (though my name is the same in both passports) but at check-in I always hand both and then let them figure out which one they want to use to issue the ticket. (In the past I used to just give them the passport I had deemed to be the correct one but the been asked to show them the other as well, so now a days I just supply both passports when checking-in).